# USE LIKE with php variable

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem using `LIKE` with PHP variables. I would like to select, based on a username, what matches the username in the DB. Here is my code:

```
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "1234";
$dbname = "coffeecorner";
$connection = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

$user = $_SESSION['username'];  

$sql  = "select username ";
$sql .= "from add_reservation";
$sql .= "where username like" . $user;
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

if(!$result)
{
   die("database query fail!" . mysqli_error($connection));
}
```

[image]

**Error**

> database query fail! You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'likeipin' at line 1

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like

Comment: The argument to `LIKE` has to be a string, so it needs quotes around it. But you should learn to use prepared statements with `mysqli_stmt_bind_param` instead of substituting variables into the SQL.

Comment: Why do you need to use `LIKE`? If you're looking for a specific username, it should be `=`, not `LIKE`. You use `LIKE` when you're trying to match a pattern with wildcards in it.

Comment: Your actual `LIKE` clause should be similar to this: `where username like '%Mond%'` ... currently, you are missing a space.  And please use prepared statements here.

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even
[if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: @Barmar I have change my code to '$sql .= "where username = " . $user;' and it throw an error ** database query fail!You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= ipin' at line 1**

Comment: You're still missing the quotes: `$sql .= "where username = '" . $user  "';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need quotes around the username. Also, if you're using `LIKE` to match a pattern, you should have wildcards in it.

```
$sql .= "where username likem '%$user%'";
```

But it's better to use a parametrized query.

```
$sql = 'SELECT username
        FROM add_reservation
        WHERE username like ?';
$user_pattern = "%$user%";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, $sql);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $user_pattern);
$result = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
if (!$result) {
    die("database query fail!" . mysqli_error($connection));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You neeed to add a little a space after like :

```
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "1234";
$dbname = "coffeecorner";
$connection = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

$user = $_SESSION['username'];  

$sql  = "select username ";
$sql .= "from add_reservation";
$sql .= "where username like " . $user;
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

if(!$result)
{
  die("database query fail!" . mysqli_error($connection));
}
```

check the error message :
database query fail!You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'likeipin' at line 1

the word `like` is stuck with the username forming a single string `likeipin` ; it should be `like ipin` meaning `$sql .= "where username like " . $user;`

Be carefull on session, session_start should be used before accessing session  variable.

You can use this query string : `$sql = "SELECT username FROM  add_reservation
        WHERE  username LIKE '%". mysql_real_escape_string($user) ."%'"` or this one   :
           `$sql = "SELECT username FROM  add_reservation
            WHERE  username LIKE '%".$user."%'"`
Hope it help.

Comment: I have add a space ' $sql .= "where username like " . $user; ' , is throw an error ==>  'database query fail!You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'like ipin' at line 1'

Comment: session_start() has been declared in the beginning of the code

Answer (score 0):

after a few hours thinking and trying i have found the solution. this a the new code. We need to input a braces () on it;

```
if(session_id()=='' || isset($_SESSION['username'])){

$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "1234";
$dbname = "coffeecorner";
$connection = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

$user = $_SESSION['username'];  

$sql  = "(SELECT * FROM add_reservation WHERE username like '$user')";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

if(!$result)
{
   die("database query fail!" . mysqli_error($connection) . mysqli_errno($connection));
}
```

Hope it helped !

Comment: The parentheses are totally unnecessary.

Comment: I didn't say they're wrong, they're just unnecessary. You only need parentheses around a query when you're using it as a subquery. If it's the main query, they're redundant, and it should work just as well without them.